# How can i check if a javascript method is supported by my node version

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use `reduce()` javascript method in my node application. My node version is 4.2.6. How can I check if I can use this method without breaking my application.

Thank you.

Comment: http://node.green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported.You can check it from 
http://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-typed-arrays--TypedArray--prototype-reduce

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches on how to test javascript methods supporting.

**1.** Compatibility tables.

For example, [this one](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/). Searching for `Array methods` rows, since the `.reduce` is a ES5 extension of the `Array.prototype`, we see that Node 4 supports it well. [Node.geen](http://node.green/#ES2015) tables also work. So, the particular answer for Node 4.2.6 is **yes**, it supports `Array.prototype.reduce`.

**2.** Manual check.

Also, depends on your needs, you may check it programmatically right in the code:

```
if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
  // no .reduce()
}
```

This could be useful for example if you want to polyfill missing method manually.